# In android and iOS mobile app encountered an invalid input error message

Tags: android, ios

I have a form with 4 fields and when I submit it after I input data , it’s displayed pop-up message

> invalid input

Comment: Any inputs? I have googled already and can’t find the right answer!

Comment: I assume you put in invalid data into these 4 fields... Post some code of your app/website, with the given information it's not possible to help you.

Comment: Try to submit data using postman and see what is your server responds fo that api. Also do some debugging too.

Answer (score 0):

Place breakpoints after each text field and see what data is getting stored into that particular text field. Then during submission see the response. Also check it through Postman.

Answer (score 0):

It’s apk generated hence can’t use simulator to do this in my environment hence can’t do it . The apk is in UAT environment . Banks